# select mtcars dataset start with name with letter "M"

Tags: r, dataset, extract

I try to extract data from the mtcars dataset in R, specifically those car with name start with 'M', however the name of the car is not a variable, so I can not do some thing like

```
Subset <- mtcars[grep("M", mtcars$name), ]
```

Is there anybody know how to solve this? 
Thank you

Comment: You can get the names with `rownames(mtcars)`

Answer (score 6):

@Pumpkin C - Not sure, why this got negative votes. The car names are `rownames` in `mtcars` dataset. Following will produce the desired output:

```
> mtcars[grep('^M', rownames(mtcars)),]

               mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Merc 240D     24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230      22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280      19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C     17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE    16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL    17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC   15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One question, maybe too simple, is how did you know the these car name is called'rownames' in the mtcars, since if i print the mtcars or use names(mtcars), it will give me start from mpg, cyl...... So I am kind of confused I get the 'rownames'

Comment: `print(mtcars)` will display the entire data set along with its `rownames`. `names(mtcars)` will only display `column` names (reason you don't see the car names). As suggested by @G5W in the comment, `rownames(mtcars)` displays the `rownames` of a data frame

Answer (score 1):

@Sagar's answer is nice and concise.  I'm just adding this here in case a [tidyverse](http://www.tidyverse.org/) approach is preferred.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
library(stringr)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  filter(str_detect(rowname, "^M"))

#>          rowname  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1      Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3      Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> 4       Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> 5       Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> 6      Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> 7     Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> 8     Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> 9    Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> 10 Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Sagar's answer and markdly's tidyverse approach by including a `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)
dat[rn %like% "^M"]
#                rn  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#  1:     Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#  2: Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#  3:     Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#  4:      Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#  5:      Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#  6:     Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#  7:    Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#  8:    Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#  9:   Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# 10: Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: This is cool! is this data.table kinda like the panda in python?